# sqoop + cloudera manger jdbc driver not found

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-manager

I am trying to set up the JDBC driver for sqoop in cloudera manager.

**Here is some background on my setup:**
1) I have a 5 machine Hadoop cluster running CDH 4.5 on ubundu
2) Installed sqoop through cloudera manager

I have already downloaded the latest JDBC  mysqlconnector jar and copied that to the following locations:

sudo cp /home/clouderasudo/jbdcDriver/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/

sudo cp /home/clouderasudo/jbdcDriver/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar /usr/lib/oozie/lib/

But it still get below an error when I try to set up a new job in sqoop with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as the JDBC driver class:

**Can't load specified driver**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to copy the database driver file in directory that contains sqoop library, in my case it is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/sqoop/lib

- Savio

Answer (score 0):

for me it was

hdfs path: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20140909154837/sqoop

restart oozie in cloudera manager